# How to convert date dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM to mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss: am throwing invalid cast exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, datetime

I have a property (`string`) named as `cdate`  in this format 
`25/01/2019 12:41:50 AM`

I want my output to look like this 
 `01/25/2019 12:41:50 AM`

 My code is throwing an invalid cast exception error.

I am a rookie in `C#`

Already I have tried this but it's not working
`cdate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss")`

Comment: Is `cdate` of type `DateTime`?

Comment: Would you please show us the code that you are using. What does "it's not working" mean.

Answer (score 3):

As you've stated in a comment to another answer `cdate` is of type `string`.

You'll need to parse the string to a `DateTime` and then call `ToString()` to format the date in the appropriate format

```
var cdate = "25/01/2019 12:41:50 AM";
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(cdate, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
cdate = dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt");
```

This uses `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` otherwise `/` and `:` get replaced with whatever the current culture's date and time separators are.

Answer (score 2):

What is the type of property `cdate`? I am assuming that it is of type `DateTime` and I am also assuming that you are trying to do something like this:

```
cdate = cdate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss")
```

In this case you will get a cast exception exception because you are trying to assign a `string` value to a `DateTime` variable (`DateTime.ToString` returns a `string`).

You should probably assign it to a new string variable instead of trying to assign it to `cdate`.

Edit:
Since the type of `cdate` is `string` then you should cast it to a `DateTime` object use `ToString` method to convert it to the required format.

```
cdate = DateTime 
           .ParseExact(cdate, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
           .ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: cdate is string

Comment: I've updated my answer with the proper way to convert the string to a different date time format.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one with specifying culture format(as you want en-US format). Exactly cdate is a DateTime instance here.

```
cdate.ToString("G", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-us"));
```

if you are looking for parsing DateTime from a string:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(cdate, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-us"));
```

Comment: it's string format i am trying to store it in shortdate in DB

Comment: @nikhiljain you need to put all these little details that you are putting in the comments to other people's answers in to you question.